# Powershell script to execute an EXE on remote servers in parallel

Tags: powershell

I have written a script to execute an exe on remote servers in parallel. But when the exe is executing, I'm getting an error. Can anyone help me to correct my script?

```
    ForEach ($Computer in Get-Content C:\servers.txt)
{

#To enable winrm if not already
$result = winrm id -r:$computer 2> $null
    if ($lastExitCode -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "WinRM already enabled on" $computer "..." -ForegroundColor green
    } else {
    Write-Host "Enabling WinRM on" $computer "..." -ForegroundColor red 
     \\slcmpx\c$\windows\system32\PsExec.exe \\$computer -accepteula -s C:\Windows\System32\winrm.cmd qc -quiet 

    if ($LastExitCode -eq 0) {
        \\slcmpx\c$\windows\system32\PsService.exe \\$computer restart WinRM 
        $result  = winrm id -r:$computer 2>$null

    if ($LastExitCode -eq 0) {Write-Host "WinRM successfully enabled!" -ForegroundColor green}
        else {Write-Host "WinRM not enabled!" -ForegroundColor red}

       } #end of if

    } #end of else  

       echo "$Computer"
      Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -force}

      $creds = Get-Credential
      $PSSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $creds -Authentication Credssp
      Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression -Command 'c:\windows\WUInstall.exe /install /reboot'}                             
}
```

Error:

PS C:\Users\sand\Desktop> .\pssession.ps1
WinRM already enabled on server1 ...
server1

cmdlet Get-Credential at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Credential
New-PSSession : [server1] Connecting to remote server server1 failed with the following error message : The WinRM
client cannot process the request. CredSSP authentication is currently disabled in the client configuration. Change
the client configuration and try the request again. CredSSP authentication must also be enabled in the server
configuration. Also, Group Policy must be edited to allow credential delegation to the target computer. Use gpedit.msc
and look at the following policy: Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Credentials
Delegation -> Allow Delegating Fresh Credentials.  Verify that it is enabled and configured with an SPN appropriate
for the target computer. For example, for a target computer name "myserver.domain.com", the SPN can be one of the
following: WSMAN/myserver.domain.com or WSMAN/*.domain.com For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting
Help topic.
At C:\Users\sand\Desktop\pssession.ps1:34 char:20
+       $PSSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $creds -Aut ...
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotin
   gTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : -2144108126,PSSessionOpenFailed
Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument
that is not null or empty and then try the command again.
At C:\Users\sand\Desktop\pssession.ps1:35 char:32
+        Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression -Comma ...
+                                ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand

PS C:\Users\sand\Desktop>

**Note:** `WUInstall.exe` is the tool to install patches by contacting the correspondent WSUS server in each region

Comment: You are getting Access Denied error make sure you have the correct rights to execute.

Comment: I have domain admin access and I am able to do it when I connected to the server via RDP

Answer (score 0):

try to run this command locally on remote server or by connecting PSsesion of remote serer. if you able to execute this way successfully then ensure you use same credentials in above script where you use PSsession of remote servers. e.g

New-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer -cred

Comment: I have edited the script and now I am getting above error.